# Advanced search options should be allowed to localize

Tags: bug, search, localization, russian-stackoverflow

When using [advanced search](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A176217+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+score%3A3+answers%3A1+views%3A250+title%3A%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0+body%3A%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB+isaccepted%3Ayes+hasaccepted%3Ano+inquestion%3A1234+infavorites%3A176217) options on localized sites, names of options should be allowed to localize:

> [image: advanced search]

I don't want to translate options used in search string inself, but in the result section it should be translated.

Comment: Why? Don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: @Qwertiy because result options are descriptions, and should be in target language, Russian in this case.