# Localization for multitagged RSS feed

Tags: bug, status-declined, feed, localization, russian-stackoverflow

I just tried to look at [the multitagged RSS feed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%2B%2B%20or%20c%2B%2B11%20and%20c%2B%2B14%20or%20c%2B%2B1z%20or%20c%2B%2B17) for Stack Overflow in Russian and saw that words like "or" and "and" not able to localize:

> [image: ruSO_RSS]

Original link goes from [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/):

> [image: isoRSS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is constructed from the actual search parameters - this includes search operators like `or` and `and`, which cannot be sanely localised.

The URL contains these and the title uses the passed in parameters.

Comment: It's a pity! Could I hope for fixing another [tag:localization] [issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291549/339911)?