# Please include the logical operators for tags browsing in Transifex

Tags: feature-request, localization, transifex, international-sites

Currently when you search for a combination of tags in localized Stack Overflow you get some text in English. For example in Stack Overflow en español:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+php

> Etiquetadas con [python] **or** [php]

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x+-python+-bla

> Etiquetadas con [python-3.x] **not** [python] **not** [bla]

Same in SOru:

> С метками: [python-3.x] **not** [python] **not** [bla]

Looking for the text in traducir.win I could not find it, so I assume it is somehow hardcoded. Could you include it in Transifex?

Comment: None of the advanced search operation are translated it would seem. [Example](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+or+%5Bphp%5D+user%3A77+is%3Aa).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky I use Traducir.win. The string needs to be added in Transifex.

Comment: @fedorqui Get it! Thank you! I thought the question was about something a bit different. Now I see.

Comment: Traducir.win is almost official?? <3

Comment: [Related and declined bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292313/339911) but hopefully by former SO dev. I don't suggest it as a duplicate post because I would like to make the current FR implemented!